# shadow not behind text

Tags: swift, xcode

I've made a function that is called in drawRect() inside a seperate made class for a Label. However, this draws only behind the text, and not behind the background of the label. I want to have a shadow behind the background of the label, not the text. How can I fix this? The same happens in a seperate made class for a View.

```
let COLOR_SHADOW_COLOR: CGColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor 
let COLOR_SHADOW_OFFSET = CGSize(width: 2, height: -2)
let COLOR_SHADOW_RADIUS: CGFloat = 5 
let COLOR_SHADOW_OPACITY: Float = 1.0

func setShadow(on object: UIView) {
 object.layer.shadowColor = COLOR_SHADOW_COLOR
 object.layer.shadowOpacity = COLOR_SHADOW_OPACITY
 object.layer.shadowOffset = COLOR_SHADOW_OFFSET
 object.layer.shadowRadius = COLOR_SHADOW_RADIUS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem. The background was the same color as the text, but with a lower opacity. Xcode thinks that it should draw around text then. After using the pipet on the same color, it did made the shadow behind the label and view